# Need in depth understating /Example of Task Parallelism to Read data from database/active directory and display them in grid

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I have scenario where i am fetching data from active directory and displaying it in the radGrid, but the collection of data is very big in millions, so retrieving it and displaying it in grid synchronously takes too much time. 
So to enhanced the performance we are working on asynchronous call of two task/thread where one task read some unit of data and second task/thread display those data in grid. As per my research this is easily possible using Task Parallelism but as i haven't work on  this feature of 4.0 i need any example where multiple task are created and they work paralleled on the same data to resolve my query and explore the Task Parallelism more.

Comment: why do you need to display millions of lines of data? who can read so much information? have you considered dividing your data to pages?

Comment: Use Paging. It doesn't make sense to show the user million rows.

Comment: Yes,I am using paging in my code not showing all data at a time, but the process of retrieving data on very first time taking two much time. So i want to reduce that time by using parallel programming - task, where one task get some record say 100 from active directory and another task display that 100 record in grid, parallely.

Answer (score 0):

Task parallel library and the async/await programming model are good choices for your case.

You do something like this:

```
    async Task MainRoutine()
    {
        ConcurrentQueue<string> dataQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task tRead = ReadAsync(dataQueue);
        Task tWrite = InsertIntoGridAsync(dataQueue, cts.Token);

        await tRead;
        cts.Cancel();

        await tWrite;
        //Done
    }

    async Task ReadAsync(ConcurrentQueue<string> queue)
    {

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!IsEndOfList)
            {
                string data = //Read data from database/active directory/ ...
                queue.Enqueue(data);
            }
        });
    }

    async Task InsertIntoGridAsync(ConcurrentQueue<string> queue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                string data;
                if (queue.TryDequeue(out data))
                {
                    //insert data to grid
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
```